# How to install Linux on a system with no CD-ROM drive and no USB boot option?

Tags: linux, boot, system-installation

I have an old laptop (from 2000) with a CD-ROM drive that no longer functions. BIOS offers no options to boot from the USB drive or a network. And the hard drive on the computer is empty, so I can't boot into an OS now.

What other method can I use to install Linux on this laptop so that this computer can be reused?

Comment: Can network boot be possible?

Comment: How can I check if that is possible? In BIOS, I only see the hard drive and CD-ROM drive listed as options. Should network be listed somewhere in the boot order menu?

Comment: You should enable that in the Bios.

Comment: You will have to pull the drive out and connect it to another computer that *can* boot from something suitable.

Comment: There may be an option in the BIOS setup screens named "Legacy USB". Enable that, reboot, and it might recognize your USB drive as a bootable device.

Comment: It is good to provide info about the machine itself(Brand, Model, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are many methods.

Firstly enable Network Boot in BIOS.

[image]

Requirements: Another computer with PXE boot setup.

You can use **Network install**  and install Via PXE Boot.

Here is a link that describes the whole process..(The following proces should be done in the other computer)

From windows: [Click here](http://tsengf.blogspot.in/2011/07/network-install-linux-via-tftp-hosted.html)

From Linux: [Click here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/PA-RISC-Linux-Boot-HOWTO/bootnetwork.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the laptop is still running Windows (XP or above) you can also install Ubuntu using the Windows installer. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide for details.

Comment: The hard drive on the computer is empty.

Comment: How do you know that?